# How to remove an artifact from publish

Tags: scala, sbt, publish, sbt-assembly

For publishing i'm using sbt-assembly, but the problem is that on `publish` it publishes all artifacts, which i don't need, i what just the one which is generated with assembly task. How can i remove artifacts from `packagedArtifacts` setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want to remove all the artifacts from the publish task then do it manually:

```
packagedArtifacts := Map.empty
```

Then call `addArtifact` with assembly Artifact:

```
artifact in (Compile, assembly) ~= { art =>
  art.copy(`classifier` = Some("assembly"))
}
```

Now if you call `show packagedArtifacts`, you'll see only assembly artifact